# IIS Rewrite regex rule for URL

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am trying to figure out how to write a regex for an IIS rewrite rule that matches a url.

The URL I am trying to match is:
http://www.example.com/Results/

the problem is that it is matching all URLS that come in that contain the string Results in it. I am using (Results.+) since I need it to keep the rewrite for the items coming after the slash. How can I get it to match just Results for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use line start and end like this:

```
^/?Results.*
```

Comment: For some reason IIS was not liking the $ at the end and once I took that out it was happy again. This was throwing me off and making me mad at why it wasn't working. Thanks for your help.